# How select for not used codes in this sample

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have a `int` column in my table in a `SQL` database.
I keep some of codes in this table. 
For sample range of my codes is : (1, 9).
I need to not used code in this range.

Example:
Used Codes is :

```
Select code from MyTable  -- result is 2,6,7,8,9
```

Not used codes is : 1,3,4,5

Now , how can I select this codes?  Expected result is : `1,3,4,5`

Comment: Where are you maintaining the list of codes?

Comment: @danish List of used codes is in a table in database. My real range is constant : (1000,25000)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate a list of numbers for your range (here I use `VALUES` clause), then semi-join to the "used" list

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
   (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) X (Num)
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable M WHERE M.Code = X.Num)
```

Edit:

You can replace the VALUES clause with any number table generation code.
Examples:

- [Optimizing Numbers Table Creation on SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4864758/27535)
- [What is the best way to create and populate a numbers table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1393951/27535)

Comment: Range of (1,9) is for example. My real range is (1000,25000).Now How can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you should maintain the list of valid codes in a look up table in the database and have the used codes as a foreign key field in the other table (MyTable in your post).

Assuming you have created a table to save codes with name LookUpTable that has a code id and code. In the other table, you have code id as foriegn key. Then, you can use following query:

```
SELECT  LOOKUPTABLE.Code 
FROM    LOOKUPTABLE LEFT JOIN FOREIGNKEYTABLE ON LOOKUPTABLE.ID = FOREIGNKEYTABLE.CodeID 
WHERE FOREIGNKEYTABLE.USERID IS NULL
```