# SQL Query cannot figure out issue

Tags: sql

The question I'm trying to answer is

> Write a SELECT statement that returns the CategoryName column from the
>   Categories table. Return one row for each category that has never been
>   assigned to any product in the Products table. To do that, use a
>   subquery introduced with the NOT EXISTS operator.

The Categories table includes the columns: `CategoryID` and `CategoryName`

The Products table includes the columns: `ProductID`,`CategoryID`,`ProductCode`,`ProductName`,`Description`,`ListPrice`,`DiscountPercent`,`DateAdded`

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT CategoryName
From Categories
Where NOT EXISTS(SELECT CategoryID FROM Products WHERE CategoryID IS NOT NULL)
```

Anything helps, thanks!

Comment: You need to show some attempt and tell us where you have been struck

Comment: The answer [looks like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948549/how-select-for-not-used-codes-in-this-sample).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**

Comment: @Bond: The correct close reason for this question would be "too broad" since no code was provided and OP wants the complete solution.

Comment: @juergend: Perhaps. The _"cannot figure out"_ in the title lead me to believe he must have tried something.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I got it to work with the following code:

```
SELECT CategoryName
From Categories
Where NOT EXISTS(SELECT CategoryID FROM Products)
```

It returned the desired results and fit the critiria of the question. Thanks anyway guys!